# Angularjs How to apply self-define filter

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, filter

AngularJS provides us the filter to extract the expected database with basic rules. You can type 'J' to search someone named 'The Joke'.

But How do I make AngularJS see search "The Joke" when I type TJ (First letters only) with AngularJS filter API?

I can use javascript / jQuery to do this by use for-loop and check one-by-one record, but this is not AngularJS helps.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: write a custom filter